# Building a JSON response in PHP

Tags: php, json

How would I go about building a JSON response that looks like this in PHP? The details of the

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "293",
            "title": "This is warning class event",
            "url": "http://www.example.com/",
            "class": "event-warning",
            "start": "1362938400000",
            "end": "1363197686300"
        },
        {
            "id": "294",
            "title": "This is information class ",
            "url": "http://www.example.com/",
            "class": "event-info",
            "start": "1363111200000",
            "end": "1363284086400"
        }...
}
```

Comment: Read the manual: `json_encode`.

Comment: At the time of writing this question I was unsure how to deal with the embedded arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Php provides a method

```
json_encode();
```

Used to convert into jason format

Answer (score 1):

Use **json_encode** function - https://www.php.net/json_encode

```
json_encode($your_array);
```

To decode **JSON** in PHP use **json_decode** function - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
json_decode($json)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create and array first:

```
$response = array();
$response["success"]=1;
$response["result"]=array();

$result=array();
$result["id"]="293";
$result["title"]="This is warning class event";
$result["url"]="http://www.example.com/";
$result["class"]="event-warning";
$result["start"]="1362938400000";
$result["end"]="1363197686300";
array_push($response["result"],$result);
```

and then use de json_encode function:

```
json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Build an array like this way:

```
$json = array("success" => 1,
    "result" => array(
                    array( "id" => "293", "name" => "alex"),
                    array( "id" => "293", "name" => "alex")
                )
    );
```

Then use json encode over the array

```
print json_encode($json);
```

If you want you can also set the content-type header as well.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Put those values inside an array, and use something like:

```
  $json = json_encode($array);
```

to convert it to json as you want. If you do:

```
  echo $json;
```

you'll see the Json as you expect.